# Blazor Server Application inside a Docker Container with windows Auth

Tags: docker, blazor, windows-authentication

Recently I have tried to use my blazor server application to run inside a docker windows container. I'm able to run the application fine.
The issue is we use windows authentication internally at our company and I want the application inside docker to be able to retrieve the user creds from active directory. It works fine outside of docker by going

```
var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
```

The application also runs, its just returning null when trying to get the authentication information. I have setup to use authentication and authorization in startup.

```
   services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
       .AddNegotiate();
   app.UseAuthentication();
   app.UseAuthorization();
```

I can also ping the domain controller from inside the controller. I'm wondering maybe I need some more config of the actual container and maybe install a few things to access AD/windows auth.
By default my docker file is using FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-nanoserver-1809 AS base